# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'values' aiogram,sqlite3

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram, sqlite3

выдаёт ошибку AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'values'

вот код:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands= ['sleep'])
async def sleep (message= types.Message):
   button1 = InlineKeyboardButton('Спать в центре', callback_data = '1')
   button2 = InlineKeyboardButton('Спать на краю', callback_data = '2')
   buttons = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(button1, button2)
   await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Хорошо, вебери где хочешь спать: \n \nСпать в центре кровати: безопасно, но даёт меньше здоровья и денег, чем на краю. \nСпать на краю кровати: даёт много здоровья и денег, но есть шанс попастся серенькому волчку. \n \nЕсли вы попадётесь серенькому волчку, то у вас уменьшится здоровье, и волчок украдёт немного денег. ", reply_markup= buttons)

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == '2')
async def process_callback_yes(callback: types.CallbackQuery, message= types.Message):
   rand = random.choice(["придёт", "не придёт"])

   await bot.delete_message(callback.message.chat.id, callback.message.message_id)
   await callback.message.answer("Вы легли спать на боку... Желаю удачи! ")
   await asyncio.sleep(120)
   if rand == "придёт":
       await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"О НЕТ! {user_name} УКУСИЛ ВОЛЧОК! \n-30 здоровья \n-10 денег \nДля лечения купи 'антикусь гель' в магазине: /shop")
       cursor.execute('UPDETE users SET hp= hp-30, SET money= money-10')
       db.commit()
   else:
       await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Фухххххх. {user_name} смог спокойно поспать на боку! \n+60 здоровья \n+50 денег")
       cursor.execute('UPDATE users SET hp= hp+60, SET money= money=50')
       db.commit()
```

весь лог:

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-22' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\Users\Magicscreen\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:407> exception=AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'values'")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Magicscreen\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "C:\Users\Magicscreen\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "C:\Users\Magicscreen\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\Magicscreen\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 283, in process_update
    return await self.callback_query_handlers.notify(update.callback_query)
  File "C:\Users\Magicscreen\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\Magicscreen\Desktop\серенький волчок бот\bot.py", line 72, in process_callback_yes
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"О НЕТ! {user_name} УКУСИЛ ВОЛЧОК! \n-30 здоровья \n-10 денег \nДля лечения купи 'антикусь гель' в магазине: /shop")
  File "C:\Users\Magicscreen\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\aiogram\types\fields.py", line 69, in __get__
    return self.get_value(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Magicscreen\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\aiogram\types\fields.py", line 46, in get_value
    return instance.values.get(self.alias, self.default)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Comment: В какой строке? И вообще приведите ошибку полностью в вопросе, все строки трейса

Comment: обновил вопрос, выложил весь лог ошибки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В функции async def process_callback_yes(...)

удалите message - его там нет

```
async def process_callback_yes(callback: types.CallbackQuery)
```

и обрашайтесь в этой функции так:

```
await bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id,...)
```